# jQuery AJAX functions not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a `$.get()` call from jQuery, but all I get is the following error;

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.get is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (client.js:12)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I have searched all over and I can't seem to find an answer. I'm importing jQuery using the Google CDN. (`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js`)

**Minimal Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery.get('echo/authstatus', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Complete Snippet**

```js
let denied = `<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <strong>Access Denied!</strong> Please check your username and password, then try again.
</div>`;
let granted = `<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <strong>Access Granted!</strong> Welcome, please wait while we redirect you.
</div>`;
let disabled = `<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
  <strong>Authentication disabled!</strong> Sorry, we have temporarily disabled authentication!
</div>`;

$(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery.get('echo/authstatus', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Echo Login System</title>
 <style>
  .ubuntu {
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  }
 </style>
 <script src="client.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">
<div class="jumbotron bg-dark">
 <h1 class="display-4 text-info">Echo Login System</h1>
 <p class="lead text-white-50">A JavaScript login system, by Eton.</p>
 <hr class="my-4 bg-info">
</div>

<div class="container" id="display">

</div>

<div class="container shadow" style="width:24rem">
 <h5 class="ubuntu text-info" style="padding-top: 1%">Authentication Required!</h5>
 <form>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control ubuntu" id="username" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="password" class="form-control ubuntu" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button id="login" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-top:1%;">Login</button>
 </form>
 <br>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you including other libraries on the same page? jquery is not the only one that uses `$`. Try using `jQuery.get()` if that works then you have conflicting libraries trying to use the same global

Comment: Try placing the jQuery script before your actual script, so jQuery is defined before you try to use it. Could you please post your HTML code?

Comment: @JackBashford jQuery is defined before my script.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I will try this and post an update.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have tried `jQuery.get()` and it is still returning that it's not a function.

Comment: Then you need to provide a [mcve] so we can see and test

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have edited the post to include those. The only thing missing is the server side js, which is just express to serve the page.

Comment: Sounds like you are loading another jQuery.js in the page that is a *"slim"* version. Check in browser dev tools network

Comment: @charlietfl How does that work?

Comment: If there is another script tag with a slim version of jQuery loaded after the tag you have shown it will wipe out the original jQuery object and slim versions don't have ajax methods

Comment: @charlietfl Ok i'll check the dev tools like you said.

Comment: Oops...it is right there in body...I didn't even look down there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185666/discussion-between-ethamitc-and-charlietfl).

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah I didnt even think of that because of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the first script tag at the bottom
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

As you have the slim version loading after the full version and overriding $.get

Comment: I literally just realized this.